# Having Trouble With Interpolating Hash Value In Regex Substitute

Tags: regex, perl

This works perfectly:

```
   my %hash1 = ( 'key1', 54812); 
  
   print ${hash1}{'key1'};       # prints 54812
```

When it comes to this:

```
my %parameters = ( 'ReferenceCode', 00000 );

my $string = q\$parameters{'ReferenceCode'}\; # here i simulate that i read it from .txt file

$string =~ s/\$(\w+)\{'(\w+)'\}/${$1}{'$2'}/g;
```

When I tried to interpolate string with regex, it gives this error:

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at....
```

Basically compiler thinks it's empty but it is not.

What should I do ?

Comment: Don't put `$2` in quotes. That's part of string literal syntax, you don't use it when the key is a variable.

Answer (score -1):

Use `e` or `ee` flags, as shown below.

But be aware using `eval` is **unsafe**. Consider passing just the key from the user input, not the entire perl variable (or any code) instead:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %parameters = ( 'ReferenceCode', 00000 );

my $string;

$string = q\$parameters{'ReferenceCode'}\;
$string =~ s/\$(\w+)\{'(\w+)'\}/$&/eg;
print("$string\n");
# $parameters{'ReferenceCode'}

$string = q\$parameters{'ReferenceCode'}\;
$string =~ s/\$(\w+)\{'(\w+)'\}/$&/eeg;
print("$string\n");
# 0
```

These flags are used:
`/e` : Evaluate `REPLACEMENT` as an expression in `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/`
`/ee` :  Evaluate `REPLACEMENT` as a string then `eval` the result.

Answer (score -1):

Symbolic references (using the name of a variable as a reference) only works for package variables. And they're a really bad idea, which is why we always use `use strict;` to prevent ourselves from using them (and for a couple of other reasons).

One solution:

```perl
my %vars = (
   parameters => {
      ReferenceCode => '00000',
   },
);

my $template = q{$parameters{'ReferenceCode'}};

my $output = $template =~ s{
   \$(\w+)\{'(\w+)'\}
}{
   exists( $vars{ $1 } ) && exists( $vars{ $1 }{ $2 } ) 
   ? $vars{ $1 }{ $2 }
   : $&
}xegr;
```

Note that your templating system doesn't have any form of escaping, which is problematic. Have you considered using a existing templating system instead of reinventing the wheel?

```perl
use Template qw( );

my %vars = (
   parameters => {
      ReferenceCode => '00000',
   },
);

my $template = q{[% parameters.ReferenceCode %]};

my $tt = Template->new();
$tt->process( \$template, \%vars, my $output)
   or die( $tt->error() );
```